# Use integration by parts to express $I(2n) =$ Integral of $\tan^{2n}x\mathrm{d}x$ in terms of $I(2n − 2)$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

(a) Use integration by parts to express
$$I_{2n} = \int\tan^{2n}x dx$$ 
in terms of $I_{2n − 2}$

(b) Hence show that
$$ \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{1}{\tan^{4}x}dx =\frac{\pi}{4} − \cfrac{2}{3}$$

For part (a), I've tried turning $\tan^{2n}x$ into $\tan^{2n-2}x\tan^{2}x$ and then using integration by parts, but the answer is messy and i can't simplify it in terms of $I_{2n -2}$.

For part (b), I don't know where to start from after using the solution below for part (a).

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. Please use [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write your question. Also, please show the calculations you did. It might be good to know that $D\tan x=1+\tan^2x$.

Comment: Please do not modify your question after answers are posted.

Comment: A user "ENG1091" posted as a now deleted answer the following: "Alexio: It does you no good to ask here for answers to your ENG10191 assignment questions. It will not help you prepare for your final exam." This might explain why the OP had tried to deface their question.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Notice, we have $$I_{2n}=\int\tan^{2n}(x)\ dx$$
$$=\int\tan^{2n-2}(x)\tan^2 (x)\ dx$$
$$=\int\tan^{2n-2}(x)(\sec^2 (x)-1)\ dx$$
$$=\int\tan^{2n-2}(x)\sec^2 (x)\ dx-\int\tan^{2n-2}(x)\ dx$$
$$=\int(\tan (x))^{2n-2}d(\tan(x))-I_{2n-2}$$

$$\color{red}{I_{2n}=\frac{\tan^{2n-1}(x)}{2n-1}-I_{2n-2}}$$

Comment: Yes, notice $\int x^n\ dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$

Comment: @Alex part (b) is just part (a) with $n = -2$

Answer (score 0):

Part (a) has been answered. So I will just work on part (b). Using part (a),

$$ I_0 = \frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{-1} - I_{-2} = \frac{(\tan(x))^{-1}}{-1} - \left( \frac{(\tan(x))^{-3} }{-3} - I_{-4}\right)$$

Thus

$$I_{-4} = I_0 + \frac{1}{\tan x} - \frac{1}{3(\tan x)^3} .$$

As $I_0 = \int 1 dx =x +C$, we have

$$\int \frac{1}{\tan^4x} dx = x+ \frac{1}{\tan x} - \frac{1}{3(\tan x)^3}  +C. $$

$$
\begin{split}\Rightarrow \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\tan ^4 x}dx &= 
x+ \frac{1}{\tan x} - \frac{1}{3(\tan x)^3}\bigg|_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} + 0 - 0 - \left( \frac{\pi}{4} + 1 - \frac{1}{3}\right) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac 23. 
\end{split}$$

Note that those zero's come from

$$\frac{1}{\tan \frac{\pi}{2}} "=" \frac{1}{\infty} = 0.$$